# Nginx ingress not saving auth cache?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have deployed on GKE a toy app to test against [Nginx Ingress Controller auth](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication) cache system. Here's a very simplistic diagram to show the current deploy:
[image]

This is the hello app ingress definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://example.com/be/auth/verify_tenant"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-method: GET
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer foo.bar";
      proxy_set_header X-Tenant-Slug tenant_name;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://example.com/be/auth/login"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-cache-key: "$request_uri"

    # To protect my backend app against potential flooding by invalid tokens,
    # I also cache refused validations, when my backend endpoint returns 401.
    # These ones are only cached for a short duration to avoid potentially filling the Nginx cache with such requests.
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-cache-duration: "200 202 5m, 401 30s"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/hello"
            backend:
              service:
                name: hello-app
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

The `https://example.com/be/auth/verify_tenant` responds with the following headers:

```
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Mon, 27 Mar 2023 09:16:56 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 22
< vary: Accept, Origin
< allow: OPTIONS, GET
< x-frame-options: DENY
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< referrer-policy: same-origin
< cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
```

For some reasons, no cache are saved on the nginx ingress pod, inspecting `/tmp/nginx/nginx-cache-auth`. I've already tested a correct behavior setting the `auth-url` to https://httpbin.org/bearer. This indeed creates in the tmp path the object:

```
> cat 4/cc/d642f1567f26999312ce18e77d4b4cc4
\k!d0j!dᥞsS
KEY: hXxx6T5vj3V3grZBQrZv/Ff8z+A=
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 27 Mar 2023 10:04:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 56
Connection: close
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

{
  "authenticated": true, 
  "token": "kdwjdkwjdwkj"
}
```

So this makes me believe there's something going on inside the ingress configuration of the backend but there's seem to be nothing fancy honestly. I have also tried returning the same exact headers as https://httpbin.org/bearer does with no success..

Backend ingress config:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: global-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-cert
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
          - path: /be
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

Backend reverse proxy configuration:

```
upstream django {
    server localhost:${DJANGO_PORT};
}

server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    listen 80;

    # Max upload size
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    # Suppress log (on/off)
    access_log on;

    location /protected {
        internal;
        alias /;
    }

    location ${DJANGO_ROOT_URL}static {
        rewrite ${DJANGO_ROOT_URL}(.*) /$1  break;

        root /;
    }

    location ${DJANGO_ROOT_URL} {
        rewrite ${DJANGO_ROOT_URL}(.*) /$1  break;

        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; # to add port to DRF resources and allow CSRF
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
```

Probably this needs more insight details. You can of course point me out and I shall provide any additions.

Comment: Is there any error message you are getting from logs or on UI ?

Comment: For which application exactly? You mean on the Nginx pod? Anyway, I couldn't record any logs really.. The backend endpoint is responding as expected with the response headers I put on the question. Simply put: using an external endpoint is making the cache work, while using the Django app doesn't (I've also tried using an Ngrok pointing directly to the backend container).

Comment: Anyway I can provide more logs if you need them

Answer (score 0):

So, I may have found by chance a solution but that only got me more confused honestly.

After some more digging, I tried with a simple ExpressJS server exploiting similar endpoint (basically returning always 200 OK) and exposing it with Ngrok just to try it out on GKE.
Surprisingly that worked as for the httpbin case, creating the cache on the Nginx Ingress container. This made me believe even more that it had to be somewhat related to Django itself.

I tried adding a toy endpoint that returned not a Django Rest Framework [Response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response) but a normal Django [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse). Exposing it with Ngrok made the Nginx auth-cache worked as expected.
Analyzing the header responses there was absolutely no differences if not on the content-type.

DRF Response

```
allow: GET, OPTIONS
content-type: application/json
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
date: Mon, 27 Mar 2023 15:59:10 GMT
ngrok-trace-id: ec9a7848abe48d5983a818110a0a728b
referrer-policy: same-origin
server: nginx/1.23.3
vary: Origin, Accept
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
content-length: 13
```

Django Response

```
allow: OPTIONS, GET
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
date: Mon, 27 Mar 2023 16:04:45 GMT
ngrok-trace-id: 41f503f33c3fbec277dac17e069e96f9
referrer-policy: same-origin
server: nginx/1.23.3
vary: Origin, Accept
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
content-length: 4
```

I don't know how Nginx Controller works under the hood but does anyone have a clue of what may be the issue? The fact is that https://httpbin.org/bearer also returns a `text/json` content-type..